# Object Mapper is appending unknown(date) text in fields annotated with @JsonProperties

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
class Root{
@JsonProperty("d")
private RootNode d;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
class RootNode {
@JsonProperty("Vendor")
private String vendor;
@JsonProperty("ToMatchInput")
private ToMatchInputDto toMatchInput;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
class ToMatchInputDto {
@JsonProperty("prop1")
private String property1;
@JsonProperty("prop2")
private String property2;
}
```

I'm setting all the values for rootObj which is an instance of the Root object defined.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true);
String payload = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rootObj);
```

the expected value of 'payload'

```
{
   "d":{
      "Vendor":"1234",
      "ToMatchInput":{
         "results":[
            {
               "prop1":"value1",
               "prop2":"value2"
            },
            {
               "prop1":"value3",
               "prop2":"value4"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

but it's creating the 'payload' as

```
{
   "d":{
      "Vendor":"1234",
      "ToMatchInput":{
         "results":[
            {
               "pro2023-05-15T12:49:07.694487699Z p1":"value1",
               "prop2":"value2"
            },
            {
               "prop1":"valu2023-05-15T12:49:07.694487699Z e3",
               "prop2":"value4"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

appending '2023-05-15T12:49:07.694487699Z ' randomly in key and value properties. the time is the server's current time.
Happening randomly for multiple fields in the JSON.

Comment: Can we have a minimal reproducible example, i.e. we need to see how you're creating your `rootObj`.

Comment: Also, is this using Jackson or a library called "objectmapper"?

Comment: @jon-hanson I'm using the setter method to set the rootObj. Creating the inner objects and then setting the properties and setting the inner objects to the rootObj. Yes using com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty.

Comment: And it is happening when I deploy it to azure, else locally on tomcat the issue is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

Since this happens on Azure deployment only, I'd guess that it is an issue of different version of JSON-JACKSON library that azure is using. Try to investigate which version is in use and make your deployment to depend on a specific version in which the problem doesn't occur. Here is how you can test if this idea is correct. There is an Open Source MgntUtils library (written and maintained by me) that has a `JsonUtils` class that is a thin wrapper over `ObjectMapper` class. But that library depends on specific version of Json-Jackson. Add it to your deployment and try to use `JsonUtils.writeObjectToJsonString(rootObj)`. If my idea is correct your problem will not occur. If that would be the case you can just use it as a solution or investigate further what is the root cause of your problem. Here is [JsonUtils javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). The library could be obtained as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc)

Comment: Azure has a json library
`<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-json</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>`
can you please explain more about the comment you wrote, getting confused.

Comment: I am suspecting that your azure json dependency is not working correctly. my answer means test it with Json-Jackson lib and if it works as expected use Json-Jackson

Comment: hi I got the issue, It was hepping due to the logs.